# How to add a icon in Listview without using Imageview and Textview

Tags: android, listview

I want to add icon in listview but I do not want to use Imageview and textview model.Is there any solution to do this ?

Here is my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listviewLinks"
        android:divider="#111111"
        android:dividerHeight="2dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my code

```
     ListView listLinks;
  ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

            for(int i = 0; i < linksArray.length(); ++i) {
                al.add(linksArray.getJSONObject(i).get("baslik"));
            }
          ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, al);
                listLinks.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here is my listview design how to add icon each listview item without using imageview and textview style

[image: Here is my listview design how to add icon each listview item without using imageview and textview style]

Comment: whats wrong with `ImageView`? do you want to write your custom view that draws your icons?

Comment: I dont want to use  Imageview , I am looking for another way to do this,Is there any xml way or  code to add icon in listview each item

Comment: you can use LinearLayout and set background for that

Comment: I guess you want to add a divider (the black line in your image)for each item?